# Server unresponsive during long running script

Tags: php, asp.net, iis-7

I have a website running on IIS7. In order to better explain my problem, I'll present it in a simple scenario. Assume I have two web pages, **index.php** and **report.php** with each of the contents as follow:

**index.php**

```
<?php echo "Hello World"; ?>
```

**report.php**

```
<?php sleep(60); //simulate a long running script like generating reports. ?>
```

Say **index.php** is the homepage of our e-commerce system where visitors will visit and **report.php** is the page where the guys in management view reports whenever they like (most likely during the day). The problem is when viewing reports which take several minutes to generate, the entire server will become unresponsive. Visitors viewing **index.php** will not get any response until the reports finished generating. This is also applicable to ASP.NET. Are there any workarounds for this?

Comment: I wouldn't expect this to happen with asp.net, since it's different threads servicing the requests. I can't speak for php though. It could be some code that is shared by all requests that blocks, which in turn would make all requests block. if this is the case, then that code really needs refactoring.

Comment: The same problem occurs in ASP.NET with the above simple scenario though using System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(60000).

Answer (score 0):

This [explains threading](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tmarq/archive/2007/07/21/asp-net-thread-usage-on-iis-7-0-and-6-0.aspx) in iis6 & 7. In essence, a new thread deals with each new incoming request. Therefore having a individual page sleep for some amount of time will have no effect on the processing of other pages. I tested this using 2 pages.

**page.aspx:**

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" %>
<%=DateTime.Now.ToString() %>
```

**index.aspx:**

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" %>
<%=DateTime.Now.ToString() %>
<% System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(10000); %>
```

Having called index.aspx, page.aspx can be called repeatedly & returns the current time every request, whilst the first request to index.aspx is sleeping.

If something is causing requests to block on your server, it could be a shared resource used across your site. in the example above, if index.aspx requested exclusive access to a resource, say a file or DB, multiple requests to page.aspx would have to wait until index.aspx finished & released the resource.

Comment: You are right, threads are not blocked on simple pages like these. However when I used `System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(10000)` in Page_Load on one of the pages of an existing DotNetNuke CMS project, it blocks incoming requests. I think no shared resources were involved with just `Sleep()` function. I wonder why.

Comment: It's likely to be a shared resource within DotNetNuke. Even when using a CMS like DNN, the threading model outlined above still holds true.